# mysql get average of column join from million records

Tags: mysql, query-performance

```
SELECT AVG(table1.column1) as a,
       table2.column2
FROM table1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
        ON table2.column2 = table1.column2
GROUP BY table2.column2 ORDER BY a DESC LIMIT 10
```

This is MySQL code. I have 1.5 Million rows in table1, 200.000 rows in table2.

I am still waiting for the query to finish.
Does anybody know a way to work in a shorter time?

Comment: Do you know what indexes are for?

Comment: And your query is wrong. `order by limit` has to be at the end.

Comment: yeah it is wrong but when i changed it. It is same result.

Comment: Add the indexes of the tables and the `explain select ...` output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have not provided enough information for us to help you. Please read this article on [asking good questions about SQL](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/), paying special attention to the section on query performance, Then please [edit] your question to tell us more.

Comment: What happens without `LEFT`?

Comment: Do both tables have `INDEX(column2)`?

Comment: same result.. Query is not finish..

Answer (score 0):

Lot of comments in the same vein but I thought I'd give a thorough answer. I'm gonna use one of my own tables/databases here for explanation. Let's take this query:

```
SELECT A.id, B.asin FROM AmazonWishlistItems A LEFT JOIN AmazonWishlistItemPrices B ON (B.asin = A.asin) WHERE A.asin LIKE "%C%"
```

This query returns about 851 and takes 0.5 seconds. If we add the word `EXPLAIN` to the query, MySQL tells us what this query is doing.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT A.id, B.asin FROM AmazonWishlistItems A LEFT JOIN AmazonWishlistItemPrices B ON (B.asin = A.asin) WHERE A.asin LIKE "%C%";
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1183 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 6594 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Important column to look at here is the `rows` as this is the number of records MySQL is having to look at and in this case for tables A and B it is having to look up all the rows even though there's only 851 that fit the condition. This is how tables can get out of hand quickly, this only has 6594 record to search through but left alone this could easily reach your 1.5 million rows.

So we can cut this down by adding an index to the table, allowing MySQL to store a reference for each record.

```
ALTER TABLE AmazonWishlistItemPrices ADD INDEX idx_asin (asin)
```

This simply says create an index called `idx_asin` and use the column `asin` to do the indexing. If we re run our EXPLAIN...

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT A.id, B.asin FROM AmazonWishlistItems A LEFT JOIN AmazonWishlistItemPrices B ON (B.asin = A.asin) WHERE A.asin LIKE "%C%";
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                | 1183 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | ref  | idx_asin      | idx_asin | 12      | mah_database.A.asin |    6 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

We're down to six rows and you can see in the `possible_keys` it's found our index. You may find that with certain joins and where clauses your indexes are being ignored that's simply MySQL saying "I'm going to have to get all the data anyway" because of the conditions you've provided in the `WHERE` condition.

It's best to use numeric keys for indexing, you can get away with some varchars but they do take up disk space. You should have a `PRIMARY KEY` on each table where possible. So look at your database structure and consider adding some indexes.

Final thing to check if your table has indexes you can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` followed by the table name.

Comment: it is not work for me. Query  is still  not response. I think query will answer me after few hours :(

Comment: Note that "%..." cannot use an index